# What does a bitwise exclusive OR do in Java?

Tags: java, scjp

Given:

```
public class Spock {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long tail = 2000L;
        Long distance = 1999L;
        Long story = 1000L;
        if ((tail > distance) ^ ((story * 2) == tail)) {
            System.out.print("1");
        }
        if ((distance + 1 != tail) ^ ((story * 2) == distance)) {
            System.out.print("2");
        }
    }
}
```

Why this sample code doesn't output anything?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In first if you get `true ^ true = false`
In second if you get `false ^ false = false`
becouse `^` - is `OR exclusive` opeartor, it's means

```
true ^ true = false  
true ^ false = true 
false ^ true = true 
false ^ false = false
```

Comment: So you can think of it like this then. If True represents a positive and False represents a negative then a negative times a positive equals a positive, a negative times a negative equals a negative, and a positive times a positive equals a negative....it's completely backwards :)

Answer (score 9):

You are using *boolean* exclusive OR and this is much the same as `!=`.  In the first case, both conditions are true and in the second, both conditions are false so neither branch is taken. (You can check this with the debugger in your IDE)

The only real difference is that `!=` has higher precedence than `&` which is higher than `^`

Answer (score 4):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2

`For ^, the result value is true if the operand values are different; otherwise, the result is false.`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't print anything because when the XOR operator is used with boolean arguments (as opposed to integers) will only return `true` if exactly one of the 2 operands is `true`.

In your first `if` both parts evaluate to `true` and `true ^ true == false`

In your second `if` both parts evaluate to `false` and `false ^ false == false`