# Why == resulting in true , in Long object

Tags: java, immutability

In this piece of code `(story * 2) == tail` is getting `True`

and `false` for `distance + 1 != tail`.

`==` checks for reference , as Long is immutable , it will false for two different objects,

Here The value `story * 2` is getting equal in reference to `tail` , but they are two different objects and not a compile time constant for pooling.

```
   public class Test2 
{
         public static void main(String [] args) {

              Long tail = 2000L;
              Long distance = 1999L;
              Long story = 1000L;

                  System.out.println(tail > distance);

                  System.out.println((story * 2) == tail);

              if((tail > distance) ^ ((story * 2) == tail))
                  System.out.print("1");

              System.out.println(distance + 1 != tail);
              System.out.println((story * 2) == distance);

              if((distance + 1 != tail) ^ ((story * 2) == distance))
              System.out.print("2");

}
```

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299643/what-does-a-bitwise-exclusive-or-do-in-java) , but no explanations for this.

Comment: Integer does but not Long , for Integer -128 to 127 are cached but not for long and surely not in this question because values are greater than 127

Comment: @Pathashu note that the values in the question are larger than 127, I suppose that caching is not the reason  here

Comment: which jdk are you using

Comment: @StinePike jdk versoin 1.6

Comment: Check out this answer: 

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149959/using-operator-in-java-to-compare-wrapper-objects

Comment: @Marek no that is not the answer , already checked it , in that integer values are less than 128 thats why it is getting true

Comment: you should accept answer of NPE :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I beleive it is due to the auto-unboxing when you do (story * 2) resulting in primitive value 2000L. And when you compare it against tail which also hold 2000L value, hence the result is true. Check here the x==y rule when one item is primitive.

[image]

Source: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=197

Comment: why Long is converted long and not reverse when == happens ??

Comment: got it thanks !! read on http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=197

Comment: Long is converted to long when you do (story * 2) due to auto-unboxing.

Comment: yes , and tail is converted to long , as == happens between primitives only , if one is primitive then object is changed to primitive

Answer (score 7):

When you perform arithmetic operations on wrapped primitives (such as `Long`), they are automatically unboxed into raw primitives (e.g. `long`).

Consider the following:

```
(story * 2) == tail
```

First, `story` is [auto-unboxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) into a `long`, and is multiplied by two. To compare the resulting `long` to the `Long` on the right-hand side, the latter is also auto-unboxed.

There is no comparison of references here.

The following code demonstrates this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long tail = 2000L;
    Long story = 1000L;
    System.out.println((story * 2) == tail);          // prints true
    System.out.println(new Long(story * 2) == tail);  // prints false
}
```

Comment: (story * 2) results in long , ok , then == is done between long and Long , why will for == Long will be auto-boxed

Comment: because one of the items of compare is primitive. In such case JVM always unbox the type to primitive.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication, addition and other operations can be carried out on primitives only...

When you carry out those operations all the boxed primitives will be unboxed and treated as primitive types.

So in your example == is checking long equality not object equality.